# Border around thumbnail class on bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the bootstrap grid to build a team page for my company. I have two columns with thumbnails (a picture, name, and title). I have tried to eliminate the default border around the thumbnails but unsuccessfully. I tried with box-shadow, border-radius, and border all set to none or 0 as I saw in other answers but it has been unsuccessful.
Any idea on how to proceed? All my code is on http://jsfiddle.net/2yLS3/2/
Any other feedback on my code is more than welcome, I only started coding in html/css three weeks ago :-)
Thanks a million!

Here is the html:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style-team-main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/bootstrap.css">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.echo-laboratories.com/icon.ico">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="nav">
        <div class="container">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://www.echo-laboratories.com">Home</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="http://www.echo-laboratories.com/team">Team</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="http://www.echo-laboratories.com/contact">Contact</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <img src="http://www.echo-laboratories.com/logo.png" />
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="title">
        <div class="container">
             <H1>Meet the Team</H1>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="main">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3"> 
                 <div class="thumbnail">
                      <a href="www.echo-laboratories.com/pj"><img src="http://tux.crystalxp.net/png/mimipunk-tux-cartoon-1820.png"/></a>
                      <div class="caption">
                           <H3>Name</H3>
                           <H4>Title</H4>                         
                      </div>
                 </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">  
                 <div class="thumbnail">                            
                      <a href="www.echo-laboratories.com/elad"><img src="http://tux.crystalxp.net/png/mimipunk-tux-cartoon-1820.png"/></a>
                      <div class="caption">
                           <H3>Name</H3>
                           <H4>Title</H4>                         
                      </div>                     
                 </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
            </div>
        </div>                          
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="mailto:founders@echo-laboratories.com" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.echo-laboratories.com/emailgrey.png"/></a></td>
                <td><a href="https://www.facebook.com/EchoLabsInc" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.echo-laboratories.com/facebookgrey.png"/></a></td>
                <td><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/company/echolabs" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.echo-laboratories.com/linkedingrey.png"/></a></td>
                <td><a href="http://www.twitter.com/pjcobut" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.echo-laboratories.com/twittergrey.png"/></a></td>
                <td><a href="https://angel.co/echo-labs" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.echo-laboratories.com/angelistgrey.png"/></a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.nav a {
    color:#818286;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:22px;
    font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:14px 50px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    top-margin:10px;
}
.nav a:hover {
    color:#39c388;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.nav li {
    display:inline;
}
.nav {
    background-color:#ffffff;
}
.nav img {
    height:15%;
    width:15%;
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:-25px;
}
.title H1 {
    color:#ffffff;
    font-size:28px;
    font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:60px;
}
.title {
    background-color:#B8B8B8;
    height:100px;
}
.body {
    background-color:#ffffff;
}
.row thumbnail {
    border:0;
    box-shadow:0;
    border-radius:0;
}
.row img {
    position:relative;
    height:90%;
    width:90%;
    margin-top:40px;
    margin-left:50%;
    margin-right:50%;
}
.row h3 {
    color:#39c388;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:26px;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:40px;
    text-align:center;
}
.row h4 {
    color:#818286;
    font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:24px;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:10px;
    text-align:center;
}
.footer {
    position:fixed;
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:60px;
    clear:both;
    background-color:#B8B8B8;
}
.footer td img {
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
}
.footer td {
    width:50px;
    padding-top:15px;
}
.footer table {
    margin:auto;
.nav a {
    color:#818286;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:22px;
    font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:14px 50px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    top-margin:10px;
}
.nav a:hover {
    color:#39c388;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.nav li {
    display:inline;
}
.nav {
    background-color:#ffffff;
}
.nav img {
    height:15%;
    width:15%;
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:-25px;
}
.title H1 {
    color:#ffffff;
    font-size:28px;
    font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:60px;
}
.title {
    background-color:#B8B8B8;
    height:100px;
}
.body {
    background-color:#ffffff;
}
.row thumbnail {
    border:0;
    box-shadow:0;
    border-radius:0;
}
.row img {
    position:relative;
    height:90%;
    width:90%;
    margin-top:40px;
    margin-left:50%;
    margin-right:50%;
}
.row h3 {
    color:#39c388;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:26px;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:40px;
    text-align:center;
}
.row h4 {
    color:#818286;
    font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:24px;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:10px;
    text-align:center;
}
.footer {
    position:fixed;
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:60px;
    clear:both;
    background-color:#B8B8B8;
}
.footer td img {
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
}
.footer td {
    width:50px;
    padding-top:15px;
}
.footer table {
    margin:auto;
}
```

Comment: change `.row thumbnail` to `.row .thumbnail`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the CSS selector `.row thumbnail` to `.row .thumbnail`

```
.row .thumbnail {
    border:0;
    box-shadow:0;
    border-radius:0;
}
```

Here you are: http://jsfiddle.net/2yLS3/3/